# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2}{x}=0$ in $D:\{\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : |y|\le x \le1\}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I need to prove that the following function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{x}$$

$$f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
   \frac{y^2}{x}  & \mbox{if } x \ne 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x = 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$

Is continuous in $D:\{\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : |y|\le x \le1\}$.

I see that for $x\ne0$ the fraction is well defined, so I study the behavior of the function when I approach the origin in $D$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2}{x}=0$$

I see from $D$ that $0\le x \le 1$, so by the Squeeze Theorem I can write

$$0\le|\frac{y^2}{x}|\le \frac{|y^2|}{x}\le\dots$$

Here I noticed that

$$|y|\le x \le1$$
$$|y|^2\le x^2 \le1$$

So I can continue the inequalities

$$\dots\frac{x^2}{x}\leq x$$

To conclude that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2}{x}=0\le\lim_{x \to 0}x=0$$

Hence $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $D$.

I'm not sure about the inequality part, can someone help me understand if this is the correct approach?

Comment: What you have done is correct but the last line can be written more transparently  as $ 0\leq f(x,y) \leq x$ on $D$ so the conclusion follows by Sqeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your previous question, I would split the analysis into cases.

Case 1: If $x=0$, then $f(x,y)=0$ by definition.

Case 2: If $x\neq0$ and $y= 0$, then

$$f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x}$$

where $f(x,y)\to 0$ as $y= 0$.

Case 3: If $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, then

$$f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x}$$

given that

$$0 \leq|y|\le x \leq 1$$

you can conclude that

$$0 \leq \frac{y^2}{x} \leq \frac{x^2}{x}=x$$

so that

$$f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x} \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x$$

then, by the Squeeze theorem, we have that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0 \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x} \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x}=0$$

So, the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $D$.